# countif value equals value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I want to count the number of values of a column that are equal to a value on the same line in another column. In the following exmaple, I want for each « ans » column the number of values matching the ones on the « ID » column:

```
ID    | ans A | ans B | ans C
------|-------|-------|------
1     |    34 |     1 |     1  
23    |    23 |    23 |    32   
4     |     4 |    16 |    25 
54    |    54 |    54 |    16 
32    |    32 |    17 |    12 
.../...
TOTAL |     4 |     3 |     1
```

I tried with `COUNTIF` but I can only enter a single value as criteria, if I enter a range I always get a 0 as result. Which function should I use?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  Could you edit your post and show the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is the values on the "total" row on the provided example. Excel 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **B8** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A2:$A6=B2:B6))
```

and copy across.

[image]

The formula in **B8** just compares column **B** to column **A** *(row-by-row)* and counts the matches.
For more info see:

[xlDynamic](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html#format)

**EDIT#1:**

The formula:

```
=SUM({1,2,3})
```

does correctly calculate in:

- GoogleSheets
- Excel 365
- the Excel web-app
- Excel 2007 / Win 7

I don't know about other environments.

Comment: Thank. If I understand correctly the `--` is used to get a range of integers instead of booleans. But in that case why is `SUMPRODUCT` working where a simple `SUM` is not?

Comment: In Excel 2016, SUM does not accept arrays as arguments. SUMPRODUCT does.

Comment: Shouldn't `SUM({1,2,3})` not work, then? I'm lost.

Comment: @gregseth  See my **EDIT#1:**